# lxml-4.3.3-cp35-cp35m-win32.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform

Tags: python, pip, lxml

I am trying to install lxml 4.3.3. on my python 3.5.1 32bit system and get the "wheel not supported" message.

I don't have web access so I downloaded the whl file and tried to install locally:

```
pip install lxml-4.3.3-cp35-cp35m-win32.whl
```

but I get:

```
lxml-4.3.3-cp35-cp35m-win32.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.
```

Making sure I have the right version:

```
C:\Temp>python

Python 3.5.1 (v3.5.1:37a07cee5969, Dec  6 2015, 01:38:48) [MSC v.1900 32 bit (Intel)] on win32

Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

>>> import platform

>>> platform.architecture()

('32bit', 'WindowsPE')
```

And looking at my pip:

```
C:\Temp>pip --version

pip 7.1.2 from c:\program files\python35-32\lib\site-packages (python 3.5)
```

Comment: where did you get this *whl*?

Comment: https://pypi.org/project/lxml/#files

Comment: why are you installing from *whl* instead of plain `pip install lxml`?

Comment: The file was https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/31/b5/7c6e0527cd96f794eac6bc3315a2cefc4074497e87c7ed2653bc38a22e2f/lxml-4.3.3-cp35-cp35m-win32.whl

Comment: Because my computer is not connected to the internet.

Comment: Can you run `python -c "from pip.pep425tags import get_supported; print(get_supported()[0])"`, what output do you get?

Comment: It can very well be that the pip is not the one that you expect. Try `python -mpip install lxml-4.3.3-cp35-cp35m-win32.whl`

Comment: @hoefling ('cp35', 'none', 'win32')

Comment: @AnttiHaapala lxml-4.3.3-cp35-cp35m-win32.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.

Comment: interesting... where did you get this **python** then :d

Comment: next idea: `python -mpip install --upgrade pip` :D

Comment: @Zilber can you also run `python -c "from distutils.sysconfig import get_config_var; print(get_config_var('ABIFLAGS'))"`, do you get an `m` printed? If yes, you can try renaming the wheel file to `lxml-4.3.3-cp35-none-win32.whl` as it seems the old version of `pip` stands in your way, but the installation should succeed after the renaming.

Comment: @hoefling I ran what you wrote and got "None". I then renamed the whl file as you suggested, and the installation was successful. Thanks a lot!